# How to find out last_login_date in passport/node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I have created a program using node js, passport, express and mongo, where first you have to register a user, and then you will be able to login. This is what my users schema looks like:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    creation_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    last_login_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

How do I find out when the user was last logged in? Ive been trying to figure this out for a while as I assume this will need to take place in the routes? This is my user route for login:

```
router.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json('Welcome ' + req.user.username);
});
```

Has anyone managed to add a last_login_date for each user?

Any clues would be helpful!

Comment: I have added a column called "last_login_time" and "last_logout_time" in my  apps/

Comment: Ok... any chance you can give more detail?

Answer (score 8):

If your already using Mongoose why not define a new static in your schema just for the purpose of logging in.

This way you keep your code together.

Also.. I know Mongoose at top level treats the update query in a findOneAndUpdate method as a $set operation, so no need to do something like this

```
query = { $set : { 'last_login_date' : Date.now() } }
```

..but... I strongly suggest you still use the $set operation to keep things clear and if you switch to another driver or plugin in time, you can still keep your all your queries. But that is just a personal habbit. If your using the Mongo Shell you'll get undesired results if you forget to use the $set on your updates.

So I would recommend that you define a static in the User schema for setting last login date and returning the updated doc so that you can use it in passport everytime a User logs in.

Your schema would look like this :

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true
},
password: {
    required: true,
    type: String
},
creation_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
last_login_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
});

UserSchema.statics.login = function login(id, callback) {
   return this.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set : { 'last_login_date' : Date.now() }, { new : true }, callback);
};
```

With this method you can get the user in session and update the last_login_date right away.

I also suggest you put that method in the deserializeUser method like Ankit Rana suggested. This way your req.user object contains the updated last_login_date.

In the code you posted you just update the last_login_date but you are not returning the updated document. So in req.user you still have the last_login_date from the previous session. You can check this by printing it to the console.

```
console.log(req.user.last_login_date); //last_login_date will not be updated
res.json('Welcome ' + req.user.username);
```

So remove all the update methods from the passport.authenticate method like this

```
router.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local'),
function(req, res) {
    // if login is successfull, the following message will be displayed
    res.json('Welcome ' + req.user.username);
```

And change your passport.deserializeUser method to this

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   User.login(id, function(err, user) {
    if(err) return done(err, null);
    done(err, user);
   });
});
```

Try it out and let me know if something does not work or is not clear

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I have managed to achieve this by doing the following:

When the user logs in, you look for the user and then you update the last_login_time. Like this:

```
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local'),
    function(req, res) {
        var query = {
            'username': req.user.username
        };
        var update = {
            last_login_date: Date.now()
        };
        var options = {
            new: true
        };
        User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        // if login is successfull, the following message will be displayed
        res.json('Welcome ' + req.user.username);
```

This works perfect, and every time the user logs in the last_login_date is updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the place where you can get user and get last login date, manually add in the user object. and property you can easily access by **req.user.last_login_date**

```
 passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if(err) return done(err, user);
        user.last_login_date = Date.now(); // Typo was here.
        done(err, user);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Im afraid this gives me an error: 'TypeError: Date.Now is not a function' on this line: 'user.last_login_date = Date.Now();'